# Redundant assumption in an exercise concerning fourier series?

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-series

So here is my problem,

I have to solve the following exercise,

Let $\phi\in L^1[0,1)$ and $\psi\in L^{\infty}[0,1)$, both of period 1 and $\int_0^1\psi(t)dt=0$. Show that
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1\phi(t)\psi(nt)dt=0$$

I composed a proof and I somehow do not see why $\int_0^1\psi(t)dt=0$ is necessary. Since usually not using an assumption in a proof means that there is a mistake in it I think that my solution is wrong. But I am not able to find the mistake. Thus I hoped someone could look over my solution.

So here is my proof:

Remark: In the previous exercise I showed that for a $\phi\in L^1[0,1]$ of period 1 the following holds
$$\int_0^1 e^{i2\pi kt}g(nt)dt=0$$
for $n>|k|$.

Consequently for a trigonometric polynomial $P(x)$ of degree strictly less than $n$ we have
$$\int_0^1 P(x)g(nt)dt=0$$

Back to the actual proof, note first that since for some $\psi\in L^{\infty}[0,1)$ we have,
$$\int_0^1|\psi(x)|dx\leq\int_0^1\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\psi(x)|$$
it follows that $ L^{\infty}[0,1)\subset L^1[0,1)$. Hence,
$$\int_0^1P(t)\psi(nt)dt=0$$
for all trigonometric polynomials with degree strictly less then $n$.

Now, let $\phi$ be a 1 periodic and integrable function. By density of trigonometric polynomials in in 1 periodic $L^1$ functions it follows that there exists a trigonometric polynomial $P$ s.t $||\phi-P||_{L^1[0,1)}<\epsilon$ for an arbitrary small $\epsilon>0$. Moreover we have that $\mathrm{deg}(P(x))=k$ for some positive integer $k$. In particular this means that choosing $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n>k$ yields,
\begin{align*}
|\int_0^1\phi(t)\psi(nt)dt|&=|\int_0^1\phi(t)\psi(nt)dt-\int_0^1P(t)\psi(nt)dt|\\
&\leq \int_0^1|\psi(nt)||\phi(t))-P(t)|dt\\
&\leq \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|\psi(t)||\phi(t))-P(t)|dt\\
&<||\psi||_{\infty}\epsilon\\
\end{align*}
Hence for $n$ large enough
$$\int_0^1\phi(t)\psi(nt)dt=0$$
and conequently 
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1\phi(t)\psi(nt)dt=0$$
$\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the previous exercise I showed that for a $g \in L^1[0,1]$ of period 1 the following holds: $$\int_0^1 e^{i2\pi kt}g(nt)dt=0$$ for $|n|>k$.

No you haven't. The assumption in that exercise excluded $k=0$. When $k=0$, you have 
$$\int_0^1 e^{i2\pi kt}g(nt)dt=\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx$$
This is why the extra assumption is made here: the integral of $g$ (which is $\psi$ in your proof) is zero.

Otherwise, your proof works.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! I totally forget about the case when $k=0$!